# MobaXTerm fails with SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_FAILURE for nonexistent channel 0 but Putty it's working

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, xterm

I am trying to connect to a server via SSH with **MobaXterm** but after inserting the password I get:

```
SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_FAILURE for nonexistent channel 0
```

I am able to connect to the server using **Putty**.

**Version**:

```
MobaXterm: 20.1 and 20.2 (latest)
Putty: 0.67
```

I would like to use MobaXterm just for the better experience and layout.

The server OS is RHEL 7.6

Comment: What version of OpenSSH is running on the server? Also, note that PuTTY 0.67 is four years old - does it work with newer versions of PuTTY or does it fail for them too?

Comment: Version: OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips
Putty was already on the client. I cannot install packages on client because I don't have the privileges. I managed to use a portable version of MobXterm.